# onvalidate in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How do I implement the OnValidate method in mvc2? I'm reading an article which shows onvalidate method but I can't find in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen an OnValidate() method in ASP.NET MVC.  You may have seen a validation mechanism in LINQ-to-SQL.

In ASP.NET MVC, I'll usually check validation like so:

```
    public ActionResult Update(SomeModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Edit", viewModel);

        // some update code...
        PutTempMessage("data updated.");

        return View("Edit", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was triyng to implement http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx in the MVC2. But not sure how to implement the business rule validation. In mvc2 there is buddy class which we can use with [MetadataType(typeof(....))] I don't know how to use this tutorial in mvc2.

Comment: Looks like the article is from an early preview of MVC1, so things certainly did change before MVC1 released.  You might search around for ModelState.IsValid to check out out they want you to do validation in MVC2.

Comment: I hope I find my answer with ModelState.IsValid